# Unexpected performance results with recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I wonder why i get unexpected performances with these two pairs of obvious examples of recursion.

The same recursive function is faster inside a struct (rec2 VS rec1) and the same recursive template function is faster with a dummy parameter (rec4 VS rec3) !

Are the C++ functions faster with more arguments ?!

Here is the code tried :

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QElapsedTimer>


constexpr std::size_t N = 28;
std::size_t counter = 0;


// non template function which take 1 argument
void rec1(std::size_t depth)
{
    ++counter;
    if ( depth < N )
    {
        rec1(depth + 1);
        rec1(depth + 1);
    }
}

// non template member which take 2 arguments (implicit this)
struct A
{
    void rec2(std::size_t depth)
    {
        ++counter;
        if ( depth < N )
        {
            rec2(depth + 1);
            rec2(depth + 1);
        }
    }
};

// template function which take 0 argument
template <std::size_t D>
void rec3()
{
    ++counter;
    rec3<D - 1>();
    rec3<D - 1>();
}

template <>
void rec3<0>()
{
    ++counter;
}

// template function which take 1 (dummy) argument
struct Foo
{
    int x;
};

template <std::size_t D>
void rec4(Foo x)
{
    ++counter;
    rec4<D - 1>(x);
    rec4<D - 1>(x);
}

template <>
void rec4<0>(Foo x)
{
    ++counter;
}


int main()
{
    QElapsedTimer t;
    t.start();
    rec1(0);
    qDebug() << "time1" << t.elapsed();
    qDebug() << "counter" << counter;
    counter = 0;
    A a;
    t.start();
    a.rec2(0);
    qDebug()<< "time2"  << t.elapsed();
    qDebug()<< "counter"  << counter;
    counter = 0;
    t.start();
    rec3<N>();
    qDebug()<< "time3"  << t.elapsed();
    qDebug()<< "counter"  << counter;
    counter = 0;
    t.start();
    rec4<N>(Foo());
    qDebug()<< "time4"  << t.elapsed();
    qDebug()<< "counter"  << counter;

    qDebug() << "fin";

    return 0;
}
```

I get this output :

```
time1 976 
counter 536870911 
time2 341 
counter 536870911 
time3 241 
counter 536870911 
time4 201 
counter 536870911 
fin
```

I have : Windows 8.1/i7 3630QM/latest Qt chaintool/c++14 enabled

Comment: What optimization level are you using?

Comment: calling-convention of member-functions (thiscall) and free-standing (cdecl) function are different ,which may account for time differences between them.

Comment: @templatetypedef : I don't know what "optimization level" is, but i use the release mode inside Qt creator, with all the default settings.

Comment: @engf-010 : maybe... I also tried to put the first function inside a namespace but it's the same. Can we have a cdecl function inside a namespace too ?

Comment: @cevik: yes ,calling conventions only specify how parameters are passed ,namespaces is just an fancy naming method ,so those things are unrelated.

Comment: could also be that the things get stored into cache after first function, hence the speedup

Comment: @cevik: normally compilers have option to change the default calling-convention. So you might play with that.

Comment: The template versions would generate linear code, not recursion.  The class method is implicitly inline, while the global function is not so that may be another difference.  Have you tried running the tests twice, or in a different order?

Comment: @engf-010 : I will try it.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm : yes, i have the same results (with a 2 ms gap) in different orders. For once, it's not Qt fault !

Comment: I tried to put conventions on rec1 and i get : 974ms without/__stdcall/__cdecl and 1125ms __fastcall/__thiscall
Changing rec1 convention isn't enought to reach rec2 performance

Comment: If you just measure one single run, there could be all kinds of things affecting the benchmark. E.g. a cold cache, the CPU still running with a lower frequency because it hasn't been busy for a long enough time and the OS hasn't bothered yet to raise the frequency, being interrupted by ... well, something like an interrupt etc. At the very least you should measure ~100 consecutive runs per function and then use the fastest time. Better yet: loop until you have not seen the time improve for ~100 consecutive runs.

Comment: @ Paul Groke 8 : I've done it several times, and i've put here the results i've found most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to look at this on Visual Studio 2015 Community.  Examining the disassembly of the compiled code, rec1 and rec2 are recursive.  They are very similar in the generated code, and although rec2 has more instructions it runs slightly faster.  rec3 and rec4 both generate a series of functions for all the different values of D in the template parameter, and in this case the compiler has eliminated many of the function calls, eliminated others, and added a larger value to count.  (For example, rec4<10> just adds 2047 to count and returns.)

So the performance difference you see is mostly due to how the compiler optimizes each version, with slight differences in how the code flows thru the CPU also a factor.

My results (time measured in seconds), compiled with /Ox /O2:

```
time1 1.03411
counter 536870911
time2 0.970455
counter 536870911
time3 0.000866
counter 536870911
time4 0.000804
counter 536870911
```

Comment: Ok, thanks you. In fact, i need to call a specific function for each depth. So i expect the optimisation to be less significant if i add a call through a function pointer array.